# Mac OSX 10.7.5 deleting files, files still in Time Machine

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac

In January of this year the Mac mini at work had its first kernel panic. I was concerned and didn't want to lose our data, so we bought an external drive for time machine. Since then I've noticed the computer deleting files at random. I can go back in time machine and find the deleted files. Sometimes these files were deleted months ago, sometimes just before the last backup.

The hard drive still has over 200gb left (internal and external) so it isn't deleting them for space. This is getting serious, as the most recent deletion spree apparently happened six months ago and was around 45gb of data.

Is this a sign of a failing HDD?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? When you say that the Mac deletes files at random, I understand that you mean that it "loses" them: that is, you didn't do anything to delete them but they somehow disappear. Is that right?

Comment: @PaulJ Yes, that is correct. I will save files to the folder and leave it for days, months, etc. until I need them again. When I go to retrieve them some files and even folders full of files (which is more common) will disappear. I try searching using Spotlight, but it doesn't seem able to find any of them. Only by going into Time Machine and using trial and error can I find them. They don't even show up in the recycling bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Disk Utility (/Applications/Utilities/) and verify your hard drive; click on the "verify disk" button.

Also, download a program like [SMART Utility](https://www.volitans-software.com/apps/smart-utility/) to check more throughly the SMART status of your hard drive. If it fails, though, which sounds quite likely, you should change it ASAP. (Good thing that at least you had Time Machine enabled).

Comment: Thank you. The Verify fixed some things, but the SMART test is Failing, so I guess we've got our work cut out for us! You've been more helpful than Google, good karma to you.